# TPath ignore case when accessing file [Java TrueZip]

Tags: java, case, truezip

Is there a way to access the file inside archive while ignoring file name case using TrueZip?

Imagine following zip archive with content:

```
MyZip.zip
-> myFolder/tExtFile.txt
-> anotherFolder/TextFiles/file.txt
-> myFile.txt
-> anotherFile.txt
-> OneMOREfile.txt
```

This is how it works:

```
TPath tPath = new TPath("MyZip.zip\\myFolder\\tExtFile.txt");
System.out.println(tPath.toFile().getName()); //prints tExtFile.txt
```

How to do the same but ignore all case, like this:

```
// note "myFolder" changed to "myfolder" and "tExtFile" to "textfile"    
TPath tPath = new TPath("MyZip.zip\\myfolder\\textfile.txt");
System.out.println(tPath.toFile().getName()); // should print tExtFile.txt
```

Code above throws `FsEntryNotFoundException ... (no such entry)`

It works for regular `java.io.File`, not sure why not for `TFile` of TrueZip or I am missing something?

**My goal is to access each file just using only lowercase for files and folders.**

**Edit: 24-03-2017**

Let's say I would like to read bytes from file inside mentioned zip archive `MyZip.zip`

```
Path tPath = new TPath("...MyZip.zip\\myFolder\\tExtFile.txt");
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(tPath); //returns bytes of the file
```

This snippet above works, but this one below does not (throws mentioned -> `FsEntryNotFoundException`). It is the same path and file just in lowercase.

```
Path tPath = new TPath("...myzip.zip\\myfolder\\textfile.txt");
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(tPath);
```

Comment: What platform (operating system) are you working on? And, just in case there are differences, which tool produced the ZIP file in question? I am asking because for me this snippet prints always what I give it as input, even if the ZIP file or path within the ZIP file does not exist at all. So probably you have more code and the error occurs somewhere else. Please share an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), not just snippets.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am working on Windows platform. There is no issue with zip archive, because it does not work on every archive I tried so far. As I mentioned in the post, I would like to perform lower-case selections. If you could give it a try, replace any character of your path for uppercase and it will not work. `.....\\myFolderInsideZip\\...` for `.....\\myfolderinsidezip\\...`

Comment: What will not work? As I said, just instantiating a `TPath` will work with any path, even non-existent ones (at least in TrueZIP 7.7.9). I want to see how you use that `TPath` later and what actually does not work. Please respect my first comment and provide more context. People around here do not like guessing (SO is not a quiz show), we want to help effectively.

Comment: What you just added is exactly what was missing! Just as I said: The code you posted originally does not throw any exceptions whatsoever. The statement `Files.readAllBytes(tPath)` is what triggers the exception!!! How can you expect and answer if you hide the very statement that causes your problem? Now at least I can answer. You could just have listened to me in the first place when I talked about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> My goal is to access each file just using only lowercase for files and folders.

But wishful thinking will not get you very far here. As a matter of fact, most file systems (except Windows types) are case-sensitive, i.e. in them it makes a big difference if you use upper- or lower-case characters. There you can even have the "same" file name in different case multiple times in the same directory. I.e. it actually makes a difference if the name is `file.txt`, `File.txt` or `file.TXT`. Windows is really an exception here, but TrueZIP does not emulate a Windows file system but a general archive file system which works for ZIP, TAR etc. on all platforms. Thus, you do not have a choice whether you use upper- or lower-case characters, but you have to use them exactly as stored in the ZIP archive.

---

**Update:** Just as a little proof, I logged into a remote Linux box with an extfs file system and did this:

```
~$ mkdir test
~$ cd test
~/test$ touch file.txt
~/test$ touch File.txt
~/test$ touch File.TXT
~/test$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 group user 0 Mar 25 00:14 File.TXT
-rw-r--r-- 1 group user 0 Mar 25 00:14 File.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 group user 0 Mar 25 00:14 file.txt
```

As you can clearly see, there are three distinct files, not just one.

And what happens if you zip those three files into an archive?

```
~/test$ zip ../files.zip *
  adding: File.TXT (stored 0%)
  adding: File.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file.txt (stored 0%)
```

Three files added. But are they still distince files in the archive or just stored under one name?

```
~/test$ unzip -l ../files.zip
Archive:  ../files.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-03-25 00:14   File.TXT
        0  2017-03-25 00:14   File.txt
        0  2017-03-25 00:14   file.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

"3 files", it says - quod erat demonstrandum.

As you can see, Windows is not the whole world. But if you copy that archive to a Windows box and unzip it there, it will only write one file to a disk with NTFS or FAT file system - which one is a matter of luck. Very bad if the three files have different contents.

---

**Update 2:** Okay, there is no solution within TrueZIP for the reasons explained in detail above, but if you want to work around it, you can do it manually like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.schlichtherle.truezip.nio.file.TPath;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    TPathHelper tPathHelper = new TPathHelper(
      new TPath(
        "../../../downloads/powershellarsenal-master.zip/" +
          "PowerShellArsenal-master\\LIB/CAPSTONE\\LIB\\X64\\LIBCAPSTONE.DLL"
      )
    );
    TPath caseSensitivePath = tPathHelper.getCaseSensitivePath();
    System.out.printf("Original path: %s%n", tPathHelper.getOriginalPath());
    System.out.printf("Case-sensitive path: %s%n", caseSensitivePath);
    System.out.printf("File size: %,d bytes%n", Files.readAllBytes(caseSensitivePath).length);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile;
import de.schlichtherle.truezip.nio.file.TPath;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class TPathHelper {
  private final TPath originalPath;
  private TPath caseSensitivePath;

  public TPathHelper(TPath tPath) {
    originalPath = tPath;
  }

  public TPath getOriginalPath() {
    return originalPath;
  }

  public TPath getCaseSensitivePath() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    if (caseSensitivePath != null)
      return caseSensitivePath;
    final TPath absolutePath = new TPath(originalPath.toFile().getCanonicalPath());
    TPath matchingPath = absolutePath.getRoot();
    for (Path subPath : absolutePath) {
      boolean matchFound = false;
      for (TFile candidateFile : matchingPath.toFile().listFiles()) {
        if (candidateFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(subPath.toString())) {
          matchFound = true;
          matchingPath = new TPath(matchingPath.toString(), candidateFile.getName());
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!matchFound)
        throw new IOException("element '" + subPath + "' not found in '" + matchingPath + "'");
    }
    caseSensitivePath = matchingPath;
    return caseSensitivePath;
  }
}
```

Of course, this is a little ugly and will just get you the first matching path if there are multiple case-insensitive matches in an archive. The algorithm will stop searching after the first match in each subdirectory. I am not particularly proud of this solution, but it was a nice exercise and you seem to insist that you want to do it this way. I just hope you are never confronted with a UNIX-style ZIP archive created on a case-sensitive file system and containing multiple possible matches.

BTW, the console log for my sample file looks like this:

```
Original path: ..\..\..\downloads\powershellarsenal-master.zip\PowerShellArsenal-master\LIB\CAPSTONE\LIB\X64\LIBCAPSTONE.DLL
Case-sensitive path: C:\Users\Alexander\Downloads\PowerShellArsenal-master.zip\PowerShellArsenal-master\Lib\Capstone\lib\x64\libcapstone.dll
File size: 3.629.294 bytes
```

Comment: Updated with Linux file system and zip archive example.

Comment: Sure, but however, does this solve my issue somehow? In Windows-only, you can't create same files or folders with same character sequence if one is already in present. So no matter of case, the TPath should point to the same file ignoring case, like NIO.2 does for local files. TPath does not. As I mentioned in rejected edit of my question, the path is case-insensitive to the point, where it access files inside archive, so you can use `myzip.zip` instead of `myZip.zip` and everything before, like:`C:\\program files\\...`.but not  `textfile.txt` instead of `Textfile.txt` inside zip.

Comment: You don't understand, do you? Everything up to `myFile.zip` is on a Windows file system, everything after that in a virtual ZIP file system. The former is case-insensitive, the latter is not. As I said, wishful thinking does not change the file system. With all due respect, the problem sits in front of the PC. The fact that you do not like the answer does not falsify it.

Comment: Update 2: I created a workaround for you. Lucky you, I had a boring Sunday afternoon and nothing better to do, waiting for guests to arrive. ;-)

Comment: Refactoring: (a) Matching algorithm is shorter and less complex now. (b) Logging now happens in application class, no longer in helper class. (c) Helper is now mock-testable, no longer relies on static method. (d) Conversion to case-sensitive path is now cached, no longer needs to search file system + ZIP file multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have *TrueZip* installed but I was also wondering how it would work in normal `Path`, so I implemented below way quite similar @kriegaex solution, you can try using `caseCheck(path)`:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Path path = Paths.get("/home/user/workspace/JParser/myfolder/yourfolder/Hisfolder/a.txt");

        Instant start = Instant.now();
        Path resolution;
        try{
            resolution = caseCheck(path);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldnt access given path", e);
        }
        Instant end = Instant.now();

        Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);

        System.out.println("Path is: " + resolution + " process took " + duration.toMillis() + "ms");

    }

    /**
     * @param path
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static Path caseCheck(Path path) throws IOException {

        Path entryPoint = path.isAbsolute() ? path.getRoot() : Paths.get(".");
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        while (counter.get() < path.getNameCount()) {
            entryPoint = Files
                    .walk(entryPoint, 1)
                    .filter(s -> checkPath(s, path, counter.get()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(()->new IllegalArgumentException("No folder found"));

            counter.getAndIncrement();

        }

        return entryPoint;

    }

    /**
     * @param s
     * @param path
     * @param index
     * @return
     */
    private static final boolean checkPath(Path s, Path path, int index){
        if (s.getFileName() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return s.getFileName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(path.getName(index).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That is actually an elegant approach. Unfortunately `Files.walk(..)` does not work in TrueZIP file systems, as described in [TRUEZIP-368](https://java.net/jira/browse/TRUEZIP-368).

Comment: Oh, it was my sunday coding as well:) At least I know now how to check case sensitive folders

Comment: I played around with TrueZIP, fixing the bug from the ticket. Then I noticed that when really using `Files.walk`, this is very slow when starting in a big file system because it does not skip irrelevant files or directories but visits **all** of them, you can only filter afterwards. What is worse, if a directory contains many ZIP files, they will all be visited recursively too. In order to optimise that I had to use `Files.walkFileTree` with my own, optimised `FileVisitor` implementation. That was fast, but `walkFileTree` does not emit a stream, so it is also not nice.

Comment: What seems to be missing in the Java NIO API is an option to walk a tree, emitting a stream of paths and at the same time filtering which files and directories to visit at all. The API as designed does not seem to satisfy this simple requirement. Or do you know a viable alternative other than using a special library or implementing everything from scratch by myself?

Comment: @kriegaex Yes I was thinking about FileVisitor but I was lazy enough:) have you tried with depth 1 parameter? then Files.walk doesnt visit subdirectories/zips. To have a quick break of visiting current dir I have added to stream first filter, Well it is not sunday but to create a stream provider or wrapper I can think of using Stream.builder() or Stream.generate() but generate is infinite so you will need to use limint(x) call

Comment: @kriegaex I just check Files.walk implementation it is using StreamSupport, all you need is to provide an iterator, maybe you can modify your visitor somehow lazy and create a stream with that? StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.DISTINCT), false)